# bithumb Api error -{'status': '5100', 'message': 'Bad Request.(Auth Data)'}

Tags: python-3.x, api

I wanted to make a program where I can check the order details of my order at Bithumb Exchange.

So I looked at the docs(https://api.bithumb.com/info/orders) and made it, but the same error code kept coming out, so I don't know what to do.

```
import time
import math
import base64
import hmac, hashlib
import urllib.parse
import requests


class XCoinAPI:
    api_url = "https://api.bithumb.com";
    api_key = "";
    api_secret = "";

    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
        self.api_key = api_key;
        self.api_secret = api_secret;

    def body_callback(self, buf):
        self.contents = buf;

    def microtime(self, get_as_float = False):
        if get_as_float:
            return time.time()
        else:
            return '%f %d' % math.modf(time.time())

    def usecTime(self) :
        mt = self.microtime(False)
        mt_array = mt.split(" ")[:2];
        return mt_array[1] + mt_array[0][2:5];

    def xcoinApiCall(self, endpoint, rgParams):
        # 1. Api-Sign and Api-Nonce information generation.
        # 2. Request related information from the Bithumb API server.
        #
        # - nonce: it is an arbitrary number that may only be used once.
        # - api_sign: API signature information created in various combinations values.

        endpoint_item_array = {
            "endpoint" : endpoint
        }


        uri_array = dict(endpoint_item_array, **rgParams) # Concatenate the two arrays.

        str_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(uri_array)

        nonce = self.usecTime()

        data = endpoint + chr(1) + str_data + chr(1) + nonce

        utf8_data = data.encode('utf-8')


        key = self.api_secret
        utf8_key = key.encode('utf-8')

        h = hmac.new(bytes(utf8_key), utf8_data, hashlib.sha512)
        hex_output = h.hexdigest()
        utf8_hex_output = hex_output.encode('utf-8')

        api_sign = base64.b64encode(utf8_hex_output)
        utf8_api_sign = api_sign.decode('utf-8')

        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Api-Key": self.api_key,
            "Api-Nonce": nonce,
            "Api-Sign": utf8_api_sign
        }


        url = self.api_url + endpoint

        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=uri_array)
        return r.json()

a = XCoinAPI(api_key="MYKEY1c", api_secret="MYKEY2")
aa= a.xcoinApiCall("/info/orders",{"order_currency":"LN","payment_currency":"BTC"})
print(aa)
```

```
{'status': '5100', 'message': 'Bad Request.(Auth Data)'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The error code 5100, bad request keeps coming up(https://apidocs.bithumb.com/docs/api-%EC%A3%BC%EC%9A%94-%EC%97%90%EB%9F%AC-%EC%BD%94%EB%93%9C)

I really don't know which code to modify.

I think it's a parameter problem with XcoinApiCall, but I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried with another endpoint with less parameters? For instance with /info/balance?

Comment: I think that you need to set the header `api-client-type` to `1` as it's what you use currently in your code (the `chr(1)`). The default value is `0` which is not what you want.